# Class relationship, NullPointerException error

Tags: java, android, realm

I have two classes of Authors and Books:

```
public class Authors extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String url_base;
    private RealmList<Books> books;
    ... getters & setters...
    public RealmList<Books> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }
    public void setBooks(RealmList<Books> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }
}

public class Books extends RealmObject {
      @PrimaryKey
     private String url_base;
     private Authors author;
         ... getters & setters...
     public Authors getAuthor() {
         return author;
     }
     public void setAuthor(Authors author) {
         this.author = author;
     }
}
```

Perform inserts:

```
Authors author = new Authors();
author.setUrl_base("url_base")

Books book = new Books();
book.setUrl_base("lala");
book.setAuthor(author);

author.getBooks().add(book);     // error comes here

realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(author);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

And the program gives java.lang.NullPointerException.

Error line : **author.getBooks().Add (book);**

What could be wrong? I ask your help.

Comment: provide your getter and setter method code for both class

Comment: Looks like your getBooks is returning null, please check where are you setting books to author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set the `books` member for your author object (as `books` is not initialized it is `null`) so `getBooks()` will return a `null`.

Make sure `books` is initialized before using it :

```
public class Authors extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String url_base;
    private RealmList<Books> books = new RealmList<Books>(); // An empty unmanaged books list. 
    ... getters & setters...
```

or use the setter method (though initializing it on construction will be more correct in this case):

```
Authors author = new Authors();
author.setUrl_base("url_base")
author.setBooks(new RealmList<Book>());
```

**UPDATE:**

As @AndreyAtapin correctly noted in the solution above the list will be unmanaged. If you want a managed list pass the required arguments as specified in the `RealmList` [api](https://realm.io/kr/docs/java/0.70.1/api/io/realm/RealmList.html) but whatever you choose the books list must be initialized before you start manipulating it

Comment: Generally this is right in Java, but is not Realm-specific. Creating a `RealmList` with constructor gives you an unmanaged list.

Comment: I see what you mean, I've updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 3):

According to Realm docs you should instantiate entity objects with special factory method:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
Authors author = realm.createObject(Authors.class);
author.setUrl_base("url_base")

Books book = realm.createObject(Books.class);
book.setUrl_base("lala");
book.setAuthor(author);

author.getBooks().add(book);     // error comes here

realm.commitTransaction();
```

When you instantiate your entities with constructor, obviously all fields are `null` by default:

```
public class Authors extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String url_base;        // = null
    private RealmList<Books> books; // = null
    ... getters & setters...
}
```

**PS:** By the way, using variables names `url_base` contradicts the Java coding conventions. You better call it `urlBase` (`setUrlBase/getUrlBase` accordingly).

Comment: Yes! So works, but the question remains with copyToRealmOrUpdate. If all of the code to run a few times, then the data in the database will be replaced or added as new?

Comment: Launched a program 2 times. On the second time issued throwDuplicatePrimaryKeyException

Comment: @SmallSani then follow giorashc's solution